# How to interpret and deserialize this JSON response

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This question originates from another topic which can be found at:
[Extract objects from JSON array to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752941/extract-objects-from-json-array-to-list)

The thing is that I'm receiving the following JSON response, and my JSON.NET deserializer doesn't understand it, but several other JSON validators like https://jsonlint.com say that it is valid.

```
[
{"value":"{\"code\":\"MO\",\"description\":\"Monday\",\"isSet\":false}","nr":1}
,{"value":"{\"code\":\"TU\",\"description\":\"Tuesday\",\"isSet\":true}","nr":2}
]
```

In my opinion the problem here is that the value object looks like a JSON object, but actually is a string. 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject keeps throwing errors until I remove the additional quotes (") and escaping chars.

So the question is, why is this response formatted like this? And how to tell the deserializer how to work with it? I'm sure that removing or replacing chars isn't the way to go.

Here is what i'm doing:

```
public class Value
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool isSet { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Value value { get; set; }
    public int nr { get; set; }
}

var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(serviceResult);
```

The above doesn't work.

For the time being I have solved the issue this way. But I keep thinking that the above, with the deserializer, is more elegant.

```
JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(serviceResult);
List<Value> values = jArray.Select(x => JObject.Parse(x["value"].ToString()).ToObject<Value>()).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you post the deserialization code?

Comment: lokks like it is nested. the values themselves are json-style attributions, and they're encoded with escaped quotes to fit the requirement for a string.

Comment: Looks like valid JSON to me, what are you trying to deserialise it to? The question you linked is not correct.

Comment: I have added my current code.

Comment: @DavidG why is that question not correct?

Comment: Just for reference, I have added my current fix/workaround as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a custom `JsonConverter`, for example something like this:

```
public class StringToObjectConverter<T> : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //This will only be needed if you also need to serlialise
        writer.WriteRaw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(reader.Value.ToString());
    }

    public override bool CanRead => true;
    //We can only work with the type T, you could expand this to cope with derived types
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(T) == objectType;
}
```

Now using these models, noting in particular the attribute on the `Value` property:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringToObjectConverter<Value>))]
    public Value value { get; set; }
    public int nr { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool isSet { get; set; }
}
```

Now it's a simple deserialisation:

```
var json = "....";
var rootObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

Comment: Right. This looks perfectly understandable. Thank you. But, then I keep thinking, if it is valid JSON according to all kind of tools, why isn't it supported OOTB by the most used JSON.NET library?

Comment: Well that's just additional complexity that, quite frankly, isn't needed. Every time James Newton (the guy who writes JSON.Net) adds another check, it slows down the parsing for everyone.

Comment: True. Any idea what the reason could be why the service developers added this additional complexity?

Comment: Er, who knows! Better to ask them. They are likely using a different library that does things differently. Note that the JSON spec doesn't say strings should be converted to objects. Imagine you had a string that looked like JSON by accident, I wouldn't want my parser to be doing anything clever with it.

Comment: Rather than [`WriteRaw()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteRaw.htm) I think you need to call [`WriteValue()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteValue_32.htm) inside `WriteJson()`.

Comment: @dbc Yeah, you may be right there, I didn't test serialisation.